# Bulk inserts into Oracle database via Python's jaydebeapi

Tags: python, oracle, jaydebeapi

I want to bulk-copy data from SQLite3 files to an Oracle DB, and do so programmatically from within a Python script using the `jaydebeapi` module.  (I have no control over the choice of Python + jaydebeapi to do this; it is imposed by the project I am collaborating in.)

One way to do it would be to dump the SQLite3 tables to temporary CSV files, and use Oracle's `LOAD DATA INFILE` command to read the CSV files.

I am looking for a way to achieve the same end result that avoids creating the intermediate temporary files.

More specifically, since I can bulk-read the SQLite3 tables into memory (with simple `SELECT` statements), what I need is the bulk-write counterpart to dump the tables from memory into the Oracle database.

---

**EDIT:** This is a recurrent task.  The largest table to be copied has typically ~100K rows.

Comment: Is this a one-time deal? How many rows?

Comment: @OldProgrammer: I've edited my post to address your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are two different "databases" you'll likely need a connection to SQLLite to do the query, and another connection to Oracle DB to do the insert.

When it comes to inserting into Oracle DB from within a Python app, you should use the cx_Oracle module's `executemany()` method:

```
data = [
    (60, "Parent 60"),
    (70, "Parent 70"),
    (80, "Parent 80"),
    (90, "Parent 90"),
    (100, "Parent 100")
]

cursor.executemany("""
        insert into ParentTable (ParentId, Description)
        values (:1, :2)""", data)
```

See https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle

Answer (score 0):

Do the SQLite3 and Oracle DB tables have the same schema? If they do, then you could try something as simple as the equivalent of this pseudocode

```
for table in sqlite3tables:
    (SELECT * FROM table)  ->  temptable
    for row in temptable
        INSERT row INTO oracletable
```

If the different databases have different schemas then you would need to write your `SELECT` statement in a more tailored fashion.

In either case, reading the Python Database API docs at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/ would be very useful to help write the solution.